# how to trigger lazy line painter svg animation when in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I currently have an SVG path animation, created using lazy line painter, on a website that is using a parallax scroll effect. Currently the animation is unseen as it's on the third page down, and by the time the user scrolls to it, it's already animated. I'm very new to javascript and jQuery and am unsure on how to trigger the animation once it's in the viewport. This is the code that I currently have:

HTML:

```
 <section id="intro1" class="background">
     <div class="content-wrapper data-section">
          <div id="icons"></div>
     </div>
</section>
```

JS:

```
var pathObj = {
    "icons": {
        "strokepath": [
            {
                "path": "M654.4,95.7c-119.8-83.9-264-97.5-397-38.3C53.1,148.4-38.9,387.6,52,591.9",
                "duration": 600
            },
            {
                "path": "M182.9,227.1l0.2-0.1C293.6,95.2,490,78.2,621.8,188.7c36.9,31,61.8,63.2,82.1,106.9",
                "duration": 600
            },
            {
                "path": "M205.1,408.8c10.5-120,116.2-208.7,236.2-198.2c8,0.7,14.7,1.6,22.6,3.2",
                "duration": 600
            }
        ],
        "dimensions": {
            "width": 728,
            "height": 606
        }
    }
}; 

 $(document).ready(function(){ 
 $('#icons').lazylinepainter( 
 {
    "svgData": pathObj,
    "strokeWidth": 10,
    "strokeColor": "#4A90E2"
}).lazylinepainter('paint'); 
 });
```

Edited code:

```
function paintLine(){
  $('#icons').lazylinepainter({
    "svgData": pathObj,
    "strokeWidth": 10,
    "strokeColor": "#4A90E2"
  }).lazylinepainter('paint'); 
}

var element_position = $('#intro1').offset().top;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_pos_test = element_position;

    if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
        paintLine();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to make your `lazylinepainter` a function that can be called at will instead of just run on page load.

Then you will need to setup an event listener for page scrolling that does some maths to check if the viewport has reached whatever point you want the drawing to start, and then calls said function to start the drawing.

To start, your line painting function could look like this:

```
function paintLine(){
  $('#icons').lazylinepainter({
    "svgData": pathObj,
    "strokeWidth": 10,
    "strokeColor": "#4A90E2"
  }).lazylinepainter('paint'); 
}
```

The event listener can be done in JQuery with something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  // calculation
  if(calculation){
    paintLine();
  }
});
```

You may also want to throttle the window scroll function so that it isn't called every moment the scroll event occurs.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried this but couldn't get the event listener for page scrolling to work and register when the element is in the viewport

Comment: I have added a section to my code above so you can see what I have so far